# Fatal error: 'upb/upb.h' file not found xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm facing this error, and I found several look-alike problems but can't solve my problem. Anyone can help?
[fatal error:upb/upb.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIYS0.png)